# Timestamps in Numbers are only partially recognized as time?

Tags: numbers, data, time

I have a column with timestamps minutes, seconds and milliseconds. Originally they looked like this

6:24,120 (it is output from the `time` command)

Pasting it into Numbers causes weird results. I can add them using `=A1+A2` but using `=sum(A1:A2)` returns 0 and if I use `average` I get an error message "Numbers can’t be divided by zero." (which is odd, because even if the sum doesn't work and returns 0, you can still perform 0/2 - it is not an invalid operation).

I have tried changing the format to `6m24s120ms`, which Numbers reformats to `6m 24s 120ms` but the result is the same as when using colons and commas as separators.

How do I make `average` and `sum` work in these data?

Comment: AVERAGE and SUM functions work correctly on data formatted with the standard Numbers duration format, i.e.  6m 24s 120ms, in my Numbers spreadsheets under Numbers 12.2.1. Have you tried applying those functions on data directly entered as durations and see if these functions work correctly then? If they are working correctly on such data, then there is a problem with your converted data, i.e. that from 6:24,120 to 6m24s120ms. On another note, how do you manage to get output from the time command with a comma representing the decimal point instead of a dot?

Comment: @Alper Yes I solved it by using duration functions rather than time.